# Regular Expression in SAS. Match word if at start or with a space before

Tags: regex, sas

I have some Text in a table and want to match a specific word, for example "good".

```
if(prxmatch("/GOOD/",UPCASE(mytablefield)) > 0 then ....
```

But this should only match when no other letter is before the G.
So i could add a space before the g

```
"/ GOOD/"
```

But it could also be at the start of the text. According to some SAS-documentation and on some answer for other languages on this site, for the start of the text ^ is used, but if i try

```
"/(( )|(^)) GOOD/" or "/(^GOOD)|( GOOD)/" or even "/^GOOD/"
```

i get no result for text starting with good. I guess this is a simple Problem, maybe related to regexsyntax in SAS, but i could not find it by googling. How can I solve this issue?

- "Good morning"-> should match
- "This is a good idea"->should match
- "I have an ungood Feeling"-> should **not** match
- "He is back 4good" -> should **not** match

Comment: Have you tried to use a word boundary? E.g. `"/\bGOOD/i"`?

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew: Thank you, i expected something simple, but did not know that it is so simple. If you want you can post this as an answer, then i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use a [**word boundary**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for that:

```
 /\bGOOD/i
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pM8gN2/1)

If you need to match a whole word, add the trailing `\b`:

```
 /\bGOOD\b/i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `FINDW` function that uses the position value and the modifier `'i'` doesn't look at case. If this is greater than 1 then you have a match:

```
DATA TEST;
    INPUT STRING $40.;
    DATALINES;
    Good morning
    This is a good idea
    I have an ungood Feeling
    He is back 4good
    goodness me
    Good boy
    ;
RUN;

DATA TEST1; SET TEST;
    POS=FINDW(STRING,'good',' ','i',1);
    IF POS>0 THEN MATCH=1;
        ELSE MATCH=0;
RUN;
```